# Why is the UK government advising, but not requesting to stay at home this weekend?

Tags: united-kingdom, covid-19, rhetoric

The background is obvious. I'm really curious about the wording. In particular, UK told that staying home this weekend is ['not a request'](https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-52155430). To me, it sounds like loosening restriction, in an unofficial way. I don't follow British politics that much so forgive me if I'm missing the obvious. What's the deal here?

Comment: I don't read that as "advising, but not requesting" ... I read it as "this is not a request, were telling everyone to stay home"

Comment: Yeah, "this is not a request" usually means "This is mandatory – do it or else"

Comment: Providing a little more of the surrounding text would have been helpful.

Comment: @billy192- _forgive me if I'm missing the obvious_ You are. You just looked at the summary at the top. Further down the page the full text is given: "This advice is not a request - it is an instruction.".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not venturing a speculation here (yet) whether that was a loosening (of the language) or not relative to prior communications on this matter, but the fuller context of that recent statement is:

> Mr Hancock - who recently ended his seven days of self-isolation after contracting the virus - said: "We cannot relax our discipline now. If we do, people will die.
>
> "I end with the advice we all know. **This advice is not a request - it is an instruction.**
>
> **"Stay at home, protect lives and then you will be doing your part."**
>
> [BBC subheading:] 'Stay at home for nurses'
>
> Ms May also appealed to the public to stay at home, saying: "This weekend is going to be very warm and it will be very tempting to go out and enjoy those summer rays.
>
> "But please, I ask to remember Aimee and Areema. Please stay at home for them."

Aimee and Areema are two (young) nurses [who recently died](https://www.theguardian.com/society/2020/apr/03/two-young-nurses-die-as-nhs-braces-for-more-coronavirus-losses) after contracting the new coronavirus.

The *Evening Standard* has chosen to headline that announcement as

> Matt Hancock orders Brits not to break coronavirus lockdown during weekend heatwave: If we relax our discipline people will die

*The Telegraph* headlined their youtube video of that press conference with

> ‘Good weather no excuse to break coronavirus social distancing rules’, says Matt Hancock

So a reasonable-enough interpretation seems to be that it's *not* a relaxation of the prior government stance. I don't know if some left-wing press has tried to spin this into something else. I've searched a bit but couldn't find such attempts/articles, so "it's probably just you[r interpretation]".

Comment: Brits might say 'this is not a request' to mean 'this is an order'.

Answer (score 2):

> To me, it sounds like loosening restriction,

To almost all British people this change in wording is a tightening of the restriction.

> Staying at home this weekend is an instruction and "not a request", Health Secretary Matt Hancock has said,

In British usage, a request is what you pass to someone who has the power to comply or refuse at their own discretion. An instruction is like an order passed to a subordinate or to someone who is not given any discretion over whether or not to comply.

The Cambridge dictionary says

> Request: the act of politely or officially asking for something
>
> Instruction: something that someone tells you to do.

So it is a similar difference to asking someone to do something or telling them to do it.